# Importance of XML, XHTML, HTML5, RAILS, PYLONS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, html, xhtml, pylons

Say, I am creating a web project. I know where I would use HTML, CSS, javascript, and PHP(WAMP).

Now, Where and why would I use XML, XHTML/HTML5(wow it says vector graphics are possible with HTML5?), and Rails or Pylons?

I'm sorry if this looks like a n00b question. I'm not asking how to learn, or what it is - just **where and why** in a web project would I - if I have to - use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use XHTML or HTML5 instead of HTML, because XHTML and HTML5 are specific versions of HTML. HTML5 is the newest one.

You would use Ruby or Python instead of PHP, because you prefer one of them over the other ones.

You would use XML when talking to a foreign web service like Twitter, because you need to serialize data in some way. You can also use JSON instead of XML.

Comment: That answered a lot - what about Rails or Pylons? Are they, just frameworks like jQuery for javascript?

Comment: Rails is a framework written in Ruby and Pylons is a framework written in Python. They run on the server, not in the browser (just like PHP). They provide code you can reuse so you don't have to write the boring stuff like connecting to databases and such.